# How to add pagination in Classed Based View with get_context_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to add pagination to my List View. I have used `paginated_by=10` but it not working. Please help me to add pagination to my view in my template. What HTML should i put in my template

View.py

```
class CompanyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'superadmin/company/company.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companies'] = Company.objects.exclude(company_name='Apollo').exclude(company_is_deleted = True).annotate(number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile'))
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ListView` instead of `TemplateView`.
Here is how.

```
class CompanyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'superadmin/company/company.html'
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'companies'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ( 
            self.queryset.exclude(company_name='Apollo')
            .exclude(company_is_deleted =True)
            .annotate(number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile'))
        )
```